# Google Sheets: get the value from data closest to the first quartile

Tags: google-sheets, quartile

For an array `[21,22,24,24,26,97]` I would like to get the median of the first half - 22. None of `QUARTILE`, `QUARTILE.EXC` or `QUARTILE.INC` does it (I did [experiments](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oKSfTUSRv6wfbC3MYspewJicbcz-4wdi_LYV4k0ZSNk/edit?usp=sharing)).

In Python numpy one can do it like:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [21, 22, 24, 24, 26, 97]
>>> np.quantile(l, 0.25, interpolation='nearest')
22
```

Is it possible in Google Sheets? What's the shortest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
=MEDIAN(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A:A;COUNTA(A:A)/2;1))
```